# Connect Power BI Desktop to .odc file

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have an .odc file that connects to a cube. It opens a pivot table.

It seems it's not possible to connect Power BI to this file directly [as seen here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-connect-odc-file-or-Excel-file-via-Power-BI-Desktop/td-p/317013), but how do I retrive the server name, database name, user id and password from this file?

Answer (score 0):

.odc files are actually a text file. Open it with any text editor and it should tell you the data source type and connection details.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just opened the .odc file with notepad. It seems that what I'm looking for is in the <odc:ConnectionString> tag. Now, the question is where do I use that string in Power BI?

Comment: Usually depends on the Provider.  If that can be translated into one of the supported Power BI sources, then use that and try to match the required details.